# ProgressBar Data Load

Tags: c#, photo

I'm trying to develop an application that allows me to search for photos, list in a `DataGridView` and preview in a `PictureBox`.
Right now I have a problem with the directories I have to indicate. If I put the same directory in both `Forms`, the `ProgressBar` has no end and the search results do not appear.
But if I remove the path from the `FormProcuraFotos` `Form`, the results already appear but the `ProgressBar` does not work well.

What do I have to change in the code to simplify the process?

`FormProcuraFotos` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _myprog
{
    public partial class FormProcuraFotos : Form
    {
        public FormProcuraFotos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // We create the DataTable here so we can create the new inside the Worker_DoWork and use it also on the Worker_RunWorkerCompleted
        DataTable tableWithPhotos;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Make the progressBar1 to look like its allways loading something
            progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            // Make it here visible
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            // Event that runs on background
            worker.DoWork += this.Worker_DoWork;

            // Event that will run after the background event as finnished
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += this.Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        // The reason for having this here was to work with the progress bar and to search for the photos and it will not block the UI Thread
        // My advice is to have them here and pass them to the next form with a constructor
        private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // We must create a list for all the files that the search it will find
            List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
            // Create the new DataTable to be used
            tableWithPhotos = new DataTable();
            tableWithPhotos.Columns.Add("Nome e formato do ficheiro (duplo clique para visualizar a imagem)");
            tableWithPhotos.Columns.Add("Caminho ( pode ser copiado Ctrl+C )");

            // What folders that we want to search for the files
            var diretorios = new List<string>() {@"\\Server\folder1\folder2"};

            // What extensions that we want to search
            var extensoes = new List<string>() { "*.jpg", "*.bmp", "*.png", "*.tiff", "*.gif" };

            // This 2 foreach are to search for the files with the extension that is on the extensoes and on all directories that are on diretorios
            // In for foreach we go through all the extensions that we want to search
            foreach (string entryExtensions in extensoes)
            {
                // Now we must go through all the directories to search for the extension that is on the entryExtensions
                foreach (string entryDirectory in diretorios)
                {
                    // SearchOption.AllDirectories search the directory and sub directorys if necessary
                    // SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly search only the directory
                    filesList.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(entryDirectory, entryExtensions, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
                }
            }

            // And now here we will add all the files that it has found into the DataTable
            foreach (string entryFiles in filesList)
            {
                DataRow row = tableWithPhotos.NewRow();
                row[0] = Path.GetFileName(entryFiles);
                row[1] = entryFiles;
                tableWithPhotos.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // With the new constructor on the FormResultadosFotos, we pass the table like this so the form can receive it
            progressBar1.Visible = false;
            var NovoForm = new FormResultadosFotos(tableWithPhotos);
            NovoForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

`FormResultadosFotos` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace _myprog
{
    public partial class FormResultadosFotos : Form
    {
        // This is the constructor that we have added to the FormResultadosFotos so it can receive the DataTable that was created on the previous form
        public FormResultadosFotos(DataTable table)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = true;
            // What can be done here to not block the UI thread if is being blocked while populating the dataGridView1, is to create another BackgroundWorker here and populate the dataGridView1 there
        }

        private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myForm = new FormPictureBox();
            string imageName = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            var img = Image.FromFile(imageName);

            myForm.pictureBox1.Image = img;
            myForm.ShowDialog();
        }
        public FormResultadosFotos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void FormFotos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // se pretendermos pesquisar em várias pastas
            List<string> diretorios = new List<string>()
            {@"\\server\folder1\folder2"};

            // se pretendermos pesquisar as várias extensões
            List<string> extensoes = new List<string>()
            {".jpg",".bmp",".png",".tiff",".gif"};

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Nome e formato do ficheiro (duplo clique para visualizar a imagem)");
            table.Columns.Add("Caminho ( pode ser copiado Ctrl+C )");
            foreach (string diretorio in diretorios)
            {
                var ficheiros = Directory.EnumerateFiles(diretorio, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
                    Where(r => extensoes.Contains(Path.GetExtension(r.ToLower())));

                foreach (var ficheiro in ficheiros)
                {
                    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                    row[0] = Path.GetFileName(ficheiro);
                    row[1] = ficheiro;
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are doing the search for the photos twice, one on the Background process then again on the load of the for the form that opens when its done, this is redundant in my point of view. What is the need to search twice the same directory?! Trying to understand that

Comment: I am trying to show that if I remove search dir from FormProcuraFotos, progressbar not shown as running. Can you edit the code that I put in my post? I know that I dont need to have redundant search. Just tryng to show my problem.

Comment: If you remove the search from `FormProcuraFotos` of course it will not show any progress bar because it does nothing and takes miliseconds to run that part of the code. Like I told you all ready several times, the Background (won't talk about Thread Class and such since its noticeable that you are missing even the basics) is to do heavy stuff on the background so it doesn't block the main thread AKA the UI while doing heavy stuff that it requires. This will be the last time I'm going to address this, check the example that I give to you, works at 100% from what you are asking

Comment: Ok. It is solved. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are missing the complete progress handling:

```
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.ProgressChanged += this.Worker_ProgressChanged;
```

then:

```
private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

and finally, you need to call it in your DoWork method:

```
var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

// this is 50%, you need to find out where and with which percentage to call
worker.ReportProgress(50);
```